# Sort string-array using java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have a vector in which which holds items of type string. i am able to add items to the vector using

```
public void AddItem(String value)
{

  data[length] = value;
  length++;
}
```

however i would like the vector to be sorted in ascending order once items are added to in any particular order for instance if i added these items

```
v.AddItem("10"); 
v.AddItem("20"); 
v.AddItem("30");
v.AddItem("40");
v.AddItem("50");
v.AddItem("90");
v.AddItem("70");
v.AddItem("80");
```

i would expect "90" to be the last item in the list. i tried using this

```
 for (int i = length- 1; i>1;i++)
  {

      if (data[length -1].compareTo(data[length]) > 0)
              {
                  data[length-1] = temp;
                  data[length]=data[length -1];
                  temp = data[length];
              }
  }
```

and it doesnt seem to work can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: If `data` were a vector, your code wouldn't compile.  It looks like you've got an `array` there.

Comment: `for (int i = length- 1; i > 1; i++)` I would say ... "wrong direction".

Comment: I'd look at using a binary-sort-insertion. This means that each insertion is only `O(logn)` as opposed to `O(nlogn)` (on average).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Arrays.sort(data);
```

instead of

```
for (int i = length- 1; i>1;i++)
      {

          if (data[length -1].compareTo(data[length]) > 0)
                  {
                      data[length-1] = temp;
                      data[length]=data[length -1];
                      temp = data[length];
                  }
      }
```

but recommend use collections, if random access - ArraysList, for example,
if consistent access to elements use LinkedList

```
List<YourType> list = new LinkedList<YourType>();
list.add(SomeValue);
Collections.sort(list);
```

If values distinct, you can use TreeSet, this Collection sort values when adding new value:

```
 Set<YourType> set = new TreeSet<YourType>();
 set.add(SomeValue);
 // Collections.sort(list) - not needed, set already sorted :)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Arrays.sort()` (notice that you need to add `import` statement):

```
import java.util.Arrays;  // or just: import java.util.*;

public void AddItem(String value)
{
  data[length] = value;
  length++;
  Arrays.sort(data);
}
```

As other people have pointed out in the comments, the data structure you use is array, not Vector.